# Reloading Datatable from sDom format in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

we have a project (SmartAdmin template to be specific) where we are trying to reload the data in the partial view for the table on certain actions by users. I just can't quite figure out what to do with this with the setup we started with.

**Datatable initialization code -**

```
function setupInProgressTable(tabletSize, phoneSize) {

    /* Data Tables */
    var responsiveHelper_in_progress = undefined;

    var breakpointDefinition = {
        tablet: Number(tabletSize),
        phone: Number(phoneSize)
    };

    /* In Progress */
    $('#in_progress').dataTable({
        "sDom": "<'dt-toolbar'<'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'f><'col-sm-6 col-xs-6 hidden-xs'C>r>" +
            "t" +
            "<'dt-toolbar-footer'<'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs'i><'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'p>>",
        "autoWidth": true,
        "preDrawCallback": function () {
            // Initialize the responsive datatables helper once.
            if (!responsiveHelper_in_progress) {
                responsiveHelper_in_progress = new ResponsiveDatatablesHelper($('#in_progress'), breakpointDefinition);
            }
        },
        "rowCallback": function (nRow) {
            responsiveHelper_in_progress.createExpandIcon(nRow);
        },
        "drawCallback": function (oSettings) {
            responsiveHelper_in_progress.respond();
        },
        "order": [[2, "asc"]]

    });
}
```

**MVC Controller action that builds up data and sends it to the partial**

```
// GET: Tier2/InProgressTable
/// <summary>
/// Gets data to supply to the In Progress Table on draw
/// </summary>
/// <returns>ActionResult - _InProgressTable Partial View</returns>
[Authorize(Roles = "Tier2.Issues.Edit.All")]
public ActionResult InProgressTable()
{
    var results = _api.Tier2.Issues.GetTier2Issue(resolved: false);
    List<Tier2IssuesViewModel> viewModel = new List<Tier2IssuesViewModel>();
    if (results.message == null)
    {
        // Get the corresponding issues for this table
        var statuses = new int[] { 2, 4 };
        var issues = results.data.Where(i => statuses.Contains(int.Parse(i.IssueStatus.id.ToString())));

        // Set items for the view model
        foreach (var item in issues)
        {
            var theIssueStatusList = GetIssueStatusList(); // Build up data for IssueStatusList

            Tier2IssuesViewModel theModel = new Tier2IssuesViewModel();
            theModel.Issue = item;
            theModel.IssueStatusList = theIssueStatusList;

            if (theModel.Issue.IssueStatus != null)
                theModel.IssueStatusList.Where(m => m.Value == theModel.Issue.IssueStatus.id.ToString()).First().Selected = true;
            viewModel.Add(theModel);
        }

        return PartialView("_InProgressTable", viewModel);
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", results.message);
    }

    return PartialView("");
}
```

Any ideas on where I should head with this?

Comment: It's not clear how you're actually populating the datatable, presumably you're looping through a `List<>` and building it manually.  If this is the case then I wonder why you're not using the API to load the data?  it would make subsequent reloads much easier.

Comment: @markpsmith I can see your point, we are manually sorting the data out in the view right now. How would you use the API to load the data in the first place? I think we are lost on that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, just change the way you populate the datatable.  Instead of passing the data in a ViewModel, you can use the datatables API to populate it using Ajax.

A simple example:

The Controller method can be simplified as it's not handling any data:

```
public ActionResult InProgressTable()
{
    return View();
}
```

Your View just needs an empty table:

```
<table id="in_progress">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Name</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

You need a new Controller method that returns the data as json:

```
public ActionResult PopulateInProgressTable()
{
   var results = _api.Tier2.Issues.GetTier2Issue;
   // read into object array 
   var result = from r in results
                select new object[]
                {
                     r.Id,
                     r.Title
                }; 
    // Get the sEcho param  
    var _sEcho = request.QueryString["sEcho"];

    // return data to datatable
    return Json(new
    {
        _sEcho,
        iTotalRecords = result.Count(),
        iTotalDisplayRecords = result.Count(),
        aaData = result
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

A few things to note here - datatables expects the json data in a specific format, so create a json object with the properties named  as in the above example. `sEcho` is a parameter send in the request, you are simply returning it unaltered. `iTotalRecords` and `iTotalDisplayRecords` are used for paging, `aaData` is the actual data.

Finally you initialise the datatable in your javascript:

```
var oTable = $('#in_progress').DataTable({
        'serverSide': true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": [your url] + '/PopulateInProgressTable'
        },
        'processing': true,
        'columns': [
            {
              'data': 0
            },
            {
               'data': 1
            }
       });
```

This needs to run after the partial view is created otherwise the table won't exist when the datatables initialisation code runs.

As mentioned earlier, this is a very simple example but it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: So I'd like to switch to this type of formatting but will this still work for instances where I want to populate some of my columns with buttons that call actions, or dropdowns that are editable and perform postbacks?

Comment: yes, there's a `render` option which allows you specify exactly what is outputted in each cell.  This can be html controls or whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the initial configuration in your partial view code. The data will need to be applied in a separate endpoint call.

To define the initial UI

```
return PartialView();
```

To return Data to your grid

```
return Json(Something.GetData(),JsonBehavior.AllowGet);
```

To setup the initial state of your `PartialView` and initially bind data, you should tie into the page load event and this is usually done in the jquery.load() function defined in your `PartialView`. 
When your partial loads, make sure that you call a controller method to return data to your grid. You may also want to add a parameter to your grid data function to indicate user's intent? However, you can load and reload your grid by binding your grid to the result of a client side ajax function that returns the json payload.

```
success(data) { bindGrid(data); }
```